# Pause thread on CountDownTimer in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview, countdowntimer

I have four balls on the screen  **red , blue , green , yellow** which has two states **ON , OFF**. Initially all of them are in **OFF** state.My requirement is that I have a string suppose ***"RBYGRBYG"*** and for every letter i want to change the state of the corresponding ball one by one **`(R->RED,B->BLUE,Y->YELLOW,G->GREEN)`** for 0.5 seconds. But my code for `playString("RBYGRBYG");` changes the state of all balls simultaneously at once for 0.5 seconds instead of changing it one by one.

```
private void playString(String str) {
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='R')
        {
            red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_on);
            new CountDownTimer(500,100){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_off);
                }
            }.start();
        }
        if(str.charAt(i)=='B')
        {
            blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_on);
            new CountDownTimer(500,100){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_off);
                }
            }.start();

        }
        if(str.charAt(i)=='G')
        {
            green.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_on);
            new CountDownTimer(500,100){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    green.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_off);
                }
            }.start();

        }
        if(str.charAt(i)=='Y')
        {
            yellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_on);
            new CountDownTimer(500,100){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    yellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_off);
                }
            }.start();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 private int i= 0; // class field

 private void playString(String str) {
     i++;
     if (i == str.length())
        i = 0;    
            if(str.charAt(i)=='R')  
    // the rest of the code the same removing one "}" at the end
```

Comment: Thanks! but what change does it make compared to my code.

Comment: In a loop all lights are changed at same time, my code changes only one light for each method call.

Comment: i want to change all lights at one method call..but one after another

Comment: If you want to change a single light every time you have to use a code that changes only one light each time, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I got it right: 
-for each letter on your string, you want to change the state of the ball(coresponding with the char in string).

Maybe try with a while instead of for, and you will increment i++ only in the function onFinish() this way it will get to the next color only if previous one has stopped.

**EDIT** Hope this helps :

```
private void playString(String str){
    while (i < str.length()){
        if(str.charAt(i)=='R'){
            red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_on);
            new CountDownTimer(500,100){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_off);
                i+=1;
            }
        }.start();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why would it run infinetly ? 
Did you also declared i above?

Comment: You can also try with a for statement like this
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(c == 'R'){
            //TO DO 
            }
        }